# How to save image in php that is not having any extension

Tags: php, image, download

I have my image in the URL `https:*******/MEb022d05131def325b861d8b9425519b2`, I want to download the image on click of the image. How can I do that?

Comment: Please take a look at the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the `Content-Type` HTTP response header field will give you a hint when you request the URL. If the server is under your control however, you could determine the image type during the request is served and provide the extension or header yourself.

Comment: Actually I am getting the image URL from the API request so I am not having control on the server. However, when I specify the content-type as image/png, or image/jpg, I downloads the blank file

Comment: Don't specify the `Content-Type` (on the request) but _observe_ it on the response.

Comment: Ok, I checked it and it came to be image/png, now how to specify the content-type in the header. I have done in this way:
header('Content-Type: image/png');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=https://api.twilio.com
/2010-04-01/Accounts/**************************/Messages/MM3492183164cc4371880ff1914812747f/Media/MEb022d05131def325b861d8b9425519b2'); 
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Connection: Keep-Alive');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
but returns blank file